# How to check second tr present or not in table with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

```
<table id="jobSkills">
<tr><th></th><th></th></tr>
<tr><td></td></tr> //i want to check this tr present or not.?
</table>
```

I have table I want to check **second tr present or not** how can I do this?

```
if($("#jobSkills tr").length > 0){ //second tr
alert("working");
}else{
alert("not-working");
}
```

I'm able to do the validation for the first tr but for the second I'm confused

Comment: `.length === 2` O.o

Comment: it should accept greater than or equal to 2 in that case.? @Andreas

Comment: @Andreas `length > 1` because if it will have more than two rows your check will fail, while second row will persist

Comment: That's why we have `<thead>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if length is greater then 1 rather then 0:

```js
if($("#jobSkills tr").length > 1){ //second tr
  alert("working");
}else{
  alert("not-working");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="jobSkills">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your first row with `<thead>` and the remaining rows in `<tbody>`

### Demo

```js
if ($("#jobSkills tbody tr").length > 0) {
  console.log("working");
} else {
  console.log("not-working");
}
```

```html
<table id="jobSkills">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately, the tr is appending thead so it's becoming complicate.

Comment: @AbdulWaheed When appending new rows target `<tbody>` ex. `$('#jobSkills tbody').append('<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>')`

Answer (score 1):

To get the second tr child `$("table tr")[1]` and to check if it exists `$("#t tr")[1]!=undefined`

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to get the second `<tr>` element of a `<table>` with pure JS is quite simple by using the selector logic.

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("#jobSkills tr:nth-of-type(2)").innerHTML);
```

```html
<table id="jobSkills">
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: OP may have more than 2 tr so `("#jobSkills tr:nth-of-type(n+2)")` is probably a better selector.

Comment: @zer00ne Could be, but `tr:nth-of-type(n+2)` tries to select all `<tr>` elements from the second on. Why would this be needed..?

Comment: Don't know why, the OP does, but it was commented as a concern.